# How to return exact matches in mySQL query using WHERE IN

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table, we'll call it "table".

It has 2 fields. We'll call them "field_1" & "field_2".

My table looks something like this:

```
=========================
| field_1   | field_2   |
=========================
| 6         | 2         |
| 6         | 3         |
| 6         | 6         |
| 6         | 7         |
| 20        | 3         |
| 20        | 6         |
| 20        | 7         |
| 6         | 9         |
=========================
```

What I'm trying to do is get a result of ONLY "6" by using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field_1 
FROM table 
WHERE field_2 IN (6, 7, 9)
```

That returns both "6" & "20".

Obviously, WHERE IN isn't doing what I want it to... what other options do I have?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT field_1 FROM table WHERE field_2 in (6,7,9) AND field_1 = 6` or better yet, `SELECT 6`, the problem is, your question as stated boils down to _I want to get field_1 value where field_1 is 6_.  At least that's the only way I can read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to get the result:

```
select field_1
from yt
where field_2 in (6, 7, 9)
group by field_1
having count(distinct field_2) = 3
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66a3b/1). The returns all rows that have a `field_2` where the value is in `6`, `7`, and `9`. The `HAVING` clause is used to make sure that you only return those that have all 3 of `field_2` values. This problem is known as [relational division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).

Comment: I see where you are going but he says in his question that he wants his existing query to return just 6 and his existing query is `IN (6, 7, 9)` not all 3 values.  But at least your answer makes sense.

Comment: @Lucas I believe the OP was showing the query that they tried to get the result. If that is not correct, then they will need to further explain.

Comment: @bluefeet, you are correct... that was the query I was trying. Your solution works great. As soon as they let me accept the answer, I will. Thank you sir!

Comment: @user2272322 You are welcome, you made it easy since you provided plenty of details in your original post.  :)